# KendoUI Tabstrip aria-controls

Tags: debugging, tabs, kendo-ui, wai-aria, javascript

I would like to know if I can control the attribute `aria-controls` of a `tabstrip` using KendoUI.

Indeed, I want to change it manualy to select a different `div` and I don't know why it's not working :

```
<ul class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset">
<li class="k-state-active k-item k-tab-on-top k-state-default k-first" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabstrip-1">
<a class="k-link">Baseball</a>
</li>
<li class="k-item k-state-default" role="tab" aria-controls="tabstrip-2">
<a class="k-link">Golf</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

to controls the `div`s :

```
<div class="k-content k-state-active" id="tabstrip-1" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" style="display: block;">
     <p>text1</p>
</div>
<div class="k-content" id="tabstrip-2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <p>Text 2</p>
</div>
```

I thought that by changing the `aria-controls` of the first tab (`tabstrip-1` to `tabstrip-2`), it would change the selection of the div.

Does anyone knows why it's not possible? What can I do to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically change the active tab? There is an API call "select(jQuery object or index)" that will change the active tab.

Comment: Yes. But inside a tab I have a form (in ajax). When I submit the form, I select a new tab. And the problem is : Before the submit, if I add a new tab with "InsertAfter". Kendo change the indexes of the tabs. So, I have to change the "ajax-update" option too to select the right tab.

Comment: You can also try selecting tabs by matching tab's heading text. 
var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");

tabStrip.select(tabStrip.tabGroup.children("li:contains('NewTab')"))

Answer (score 0):

Use the `accesskey` attribute and the `keypress` method:

```
<a id="foo" href="some url" accesskey="1">My link</a>
<script>
function keyHandler(e) 
  {
  if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 87) 
     {
     $("#tabstrip").focus();
     }
  }

$(document.body).keypress(keyHandler);
</script>
```

**References**

- [TabStrip / Keyboard navigation](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tabstrip/navigation.html)
- [Pseudo Keypress in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696500/detecting-mobile-phone-physical-button-press-in-javascript/8701016#8701016)